# How did the modern day Beis Hora'ah phenomenon develop?

Tags: history, sources-mekorot, halacha-theory, posek-psak-decisor-ruling, provenance

Here in Eretz Yisrael, we find *Batei Hora'ah* in many cities - places where a *moreh hora'ah* sits either during special times or perhaps the whole day or different *rabbonim* throughout the day answering *shailos* in all areas of Shulchan Aruch.

When did this all start?  I'm looking to find any insights people might have for how this developed or any sources as well.

My theory:

Once upon a time, I suppose, a *beis medresh* was enough because all of the *chachamim* were there. If someone had a *shailo* they went to the *beis medresh*. Nowadays, *batei medreshim* are filled with either *avreichim* in kollel, *yeshiva bachurim*, or *baalei batim* that spend some of their time learning. Generally no one in these groups of people would be qualified (or "certified") to answer *shailos* in *halacha*.

Perhaps this is why things changed? Along with the fact that a city used to have maybe one *rov* or each *kehillah* had a *rov* for themselves. In Yerushalayim alone I'm sure you could find 100s if not 1000s of people qualified to *pasken shailos* in practical *halacha*.

Comment: The Telephone, a large Kollel population, and more Frum citizen/Rov ratio